# Terminal is not opening after xrdp session

Tags: 20.04, xfce, remote-desktop, xrdp

So i set up xrdp to connect to my ubuntu 20.04 from windows 10 and was able to work with it for quite a while. Initially i did face an issue wherein if I start a new terminal from my windows the terminal would open up inside my ubuntu and I wouldn't see it from my windows.

I fixed that my adding a line to the end of the xfce4 file.

Now, i closed off my rdp session and came back to my ubuntu. First thing I noticed is the reverse of the initial problem I faced. Opening terminals in my ubuntu opens them only in the rdp session presented to windows, but I wont get the terminal here in ubuntu.

I logged off the rdp and I was able to see the firebox tabs i had opened while working via xrdp, but the terminals are not opening up and I don't know what to do?

Please help me.. :(